# ORA-12899 when creating varchar virtual column based on numeric column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a table with numeric column:

```
create table test (a number(2,0));
```

Next I want to create a virtual column based on column a:

```
alter table test add (b varchar2(3) as ('A:'||to_char(a)));
```

This results in error:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "B" (actual: 12, maximum: 42)
```

Why do I get this error? This works if I replace to_char with substr, but I'm curious how does Oracle determine the "actual" and "maximum" values?

I suspect the maximum value is related to maximum precision of numeric types (Oracle ignoring the data type precision), but I still don't quite understand this error. Character set is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is somewhat strange as presented, but when you get this message creating a virtual column, the value for `maximum` is the minimum length that you need to specify to be able to create the column.

The reason for this is that Oracle doesn't know the maximum length of the expression `to_char(a)` and assumes that it will be 40 characters: 38 places of precision for the number, plus 1 for each of the decimal point and positive/negative indicator.

Add 2 characters for "A:" and the minimum length that Oracle judges as "safe" is 42.

Answer (score 1):

Use a format with your `to_char`:

```
SQL> create table test (a number(2,0));

Table created

SQL> alter table test add (b varchar2(4) as ('A:'||to_char(a, 'fm99')));

Table altered

SQL> insert into test (a) values (99);

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from test;

  A B
--- ------------
 99 A:99
```

Interestingly, Oracle doesn't seem to check the actual length in this case in version 11.2.0.3.0:

```
SQL> insert into test (a) values (-99);

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from test;

  A B
--- ------------
 99 A:99
-99 A:-99

SQL> desc test

Name Type        Nullable Default                   Comments 
---- ----------- -------- ------------------------- -------- 
A    NUMBER(2)   Y                                           
B    VARCHAR2(4) Y        'A:'||TO_CHAR("A",'fm99') -- should be VARCHAR2(5)??
```